# I cant change the value of x label in plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot Speed-Time graph and ı want to change to x label as 2012, 2013,2014,2015,2016 as like this

[image: I want like this]

[image: my code]
With this code ı got this graph:

Could you help me please. What should ı do ?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    
data=pd.read_excel("ts80.xlsx")
Date=data["Date"]
Speed=data["Speed"]


timestamp = pd.to_datetime(Date[0:]).dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,6))
ax.plot(timestamp, Speed)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("80Avg[m/s]")
plt.title("Mean Wind Speed at 80m")
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y"))
plt.xticks([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016])
plt.show()
```

Could you please write correct code ?

Comment: try `ax.set_xticks([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016])`

Comment: it says : AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_xticks'

Comment: use data column as an index.

Comment: sorry, try `ax.set_xticks([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016])`

Comment: that is not the best way to do that, @d_kennetz. The issue is that the OP is plotting strings instead of dates. Forcing the tick labels to hard-coded values is a band aid at best.

Comment: I did. But there is no change.

Comment: In order to best answer your question, please share a minimal example of your data to reproduce your plot. Maybe have each date with a couple of relevant values. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulH could you please write all code.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're converting your dates strings to dates and then back to strings. Don't do that. Keep them as dates and then use the correct `DataFormatter` on your x-axis.

```py
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import dates
import pandas

data = pd.read_excel("ts80.xlsx")

t = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
x = data["Speed"]

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(t, x)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter("%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.YearLocator())
plt.show()
```

The reason why you want to use a proper Formatter and Locator is that it solves the general case where this code evolves into an interactive plot with a long series of data and the user can pan/zoom around. Hard-coded ticks or tick labels completely falls apart under that scenario.

Comment: @beginner123 - please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark to the left then.